# What is a proper way to disable jack-server

Tags: android, android-jack-and-jill

I want to build Android 6, 7, and 8 without `jack-server`. Compiling Android 8 with

```
make ANDROID_COMPILE_WITH_JACK:=false
```

works. But this doesn't work on 6 and 7.

Another question, is there any difference on output compiling with and without Jack?

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://source.android.com/setup/jack indicate that Jack is part of the Java toolchain for Android and is deprecated for newer build environments (since March 14, 2017), one could infer that whichever old variant of Android you are trying to build does not support compiling without Jack.

So in this case it could be an outdated build-repo issue. However since I just dived into building Android I can't tell for sure of course, it may simply be the case that its not supported (yet).